# In XAML how do you place items next to each other in a Grid

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xaml

Ok Xaml is one of my weak points, so I would really appreciate some help on this...what I am trying to achieve is adding a title, name, surname in a listbox as follow:

Mr. John Doe
Ms. John Doe
Mrs. Jane Doe

this is the xaml I have so far, and the result is the name title and surname are overlapping on top of each other:

```
<DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"  Width="60" Height="25" Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Grid.Column` attribute in the `TextBlock`. Ie:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"  Width="60" Height="25" Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0"/> 
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" /> 
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="2" />
```

Comment: Thanks that worked I knew it was something simple instead I was playing around with the margins etc and just making things complicated...Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

In each `TextBlock` you need to set `Grid.Column="?"` where ? is 0, 1, or 2.

If you don't specify a column (or row), elements will by default go to (0,0).

Answer (score 0):

For each element in the grid, if you want them in an explicit Row or Column, you must specify them.  To do this you would use `Grid.Row="X"` or `Grid.Column="X"`.  If you leave these off, the default value is 0.

In your case, you would want to do the following.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"  Width="60" Height="25" Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="2" />

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```